# Need to remove the first title considering the same attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I need to remove the first title from the body element which considering the same outputclass value for the two titles

Input XML:

```
<topic>
   <title outputclass="header">Sample</title>
   <topic>
      <title outputclass="header">Test</title>
      <topic>
         <title outputclass="section">Section</title>
            <body>
               <p outputclass="normal">Solution</p>
            </body>
      </topic>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

XSLT I'm having:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <document>
       <head>
          <title><xsl:value-of select="title[@outputclass='header']"/></title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </body>
    </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topic/title[@outputclass='header'][1]"/>

<xsl:template match="topic">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title | p">
   <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Output:

```
<document>
   <head><title>Sample</title></head>
   <body>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Solution</p>
   </body>
</document>
```

I need to remove the the first title which considering the same attribute `outputclass` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a top-level variable or parameter

```
<xsl:param name="first-output-header" select="/*/descendant::title[@outputclass = 'header'][1]"/>
```

and then use

```
<xsl:template match="$first-output-header"/>
```

at least in XSLT 3. I think it is also possible in XSLT 2 but would need to dig in the spec or find something that implements that "old" version.

Another option in XSLT 3 would be to use an accumulator to count the "header"s and check for the value e.g.

```
<xsl:accumulator name="header-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule
      match="topic/title[@outputclass = 'header']"
      select="$value + 1"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:mode use-accumulators="header-count"/>

<xsl:template match="topic/title[@outputclass = 'header'][accumulator-before('header-count') = 1]"/>
```

That would work with streaming as well.